# Admissible Heuristic Modification

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

I am currently working on a project involving a puzzle and various pathfinding algorithms. The puzzle is represented using a 2d array, and has a specific form factor. Each cell in the 2d array has a jump value, and that is the number of spaces you can move up, down, left, or right from the cell.

I am currently working on implementing A* search on this puzzle. I was thinking of using manhattan distance as an admissible heuristic for this problem, but I do not think that the conventional manhattan distance will work since movement is limited to a specific number of moves.

For example:

```
2   2   2   1   1
1   1   1   2   2
3   1   2   1   1
3   1   2   1   1
2   1   1   1   0
```

Is a possible grid. You start from the `2` in the top left cell and are trying to get to the `0` in the bottom right cell. From the start cell, you can move right two or down `2` to new spaces which have different jump values. This process repeats until the goal is reached if the puzzle is solvable.

How can I modify the manhattan distance `abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)` to incorporate moving a specific number of spaces?

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed Manhattan distance isn't an [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), e.g. starting from `P = (3,2)` you have:

```
Manhattan(P, Target) = abs(3 - 4) + abs(2 - 4) = 1 + 2 = 3
```

but the *real* distance is just `2`.

An admissible heuristic is:

```
h(P) = (P_x != Target_x) + (P_y != Target_y)
```

where

```
           | 1    if x == y
(x != y) = |
           | 0    otherwise
```

This works since for every component of the *current-position-vector* that doesn't match the corresponding component in target vector you have to take at least `1` move.